# C# Random Number Not Random Enough

Tags: c#, random, xna

C#'s Random not random enough

My goal is to get more randomness than appears to be possible using either the built in Random or the crypto RNGs.

---

Q: How can I get more randomness from a random number generator?

---

First off, I'm dealing with a single instance of Random.

I'm assigning a random velocity (XNA Vector2) to an object using this routine:

```
    public static double d2r = Math.PI / 180f;
    public static Vector2 rndV2gtHalf(float scaleFactor)
    {
        double dir = random.NextDouble() * 360 * d2r;
        return new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(dir) * scaleFactor, (float)Math.Sin(dir) * scaleFactor);
    }
```

d2r is a factor for degree to radian conversion.  For testing purposes, I put about 6000 objects on the screen each second, they go in "random" directions, from my mouse location.  Here's the result

[image]

Though the objects head out in all directions, they do so seemingly in connected streams that "wiggle".  I'm guessing that the wiggle is the result of minute randomness within the "bins" of the streams themselves.  The streams don't revolve around the center, so even with the wiggle, the coverage is less than complete.

I attempted to add more randomness to my velocity by making it depend on 3 uses of random.NextDouble.  This resulted in a large swath near 0 degrees that was nearly empty.  Apart from that empty swath, the rest of the directions were covered as before.

```
public static Vector2 rndV2gtHalf(float scaleFactor)
{
    double dir = ((random.NextDouble() + random.NextDouble() + random.NextDouble()) / 3) * 360 * d2r;
    return new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(dir) * scaleFactor, (float)Math.Sin(dir) * scaleFactor);
}
```

Clearly, this doesn't produce more randomness.
[image]

So, I thought that maybe I had combined the random numbers too soon in the process, and was fundamentally altering the stochastic nature of the number by adding.  So, I tried doing a mod on a bunch of them before converting to radians.

```
public static Vector2 rndV2gtHalf(float scaleFactor)
{
    double dir = random.NextDouble() * 360;
    dir += random.NextDouble() * 360;
    dir += random.NextDouble() * 360;
    dir += random.NextDouble() * 360;
    dir += random.NextDouble() * 360;
    dir += random.NextDouble() * 360;
    dir %= 360;
    dir *= d2r;
    return new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(dir) * scaleFactor, (float)Math.Sin(dir) * scaleFactor);
}
```

This seems to be no better than depending on a single random.NextDouble.
[image]

I read somewhere that there is a crypto random num gen that is better, but it seems to not have the native ability to produce Double-s, so I attempt to kludge those.

```
public static RandomNumberGenerator rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
public static Vector2 rndV2gtHalf(float scaleFactor)
{
    byte[] tokenData = new byte[2];
    rng.GetBytes(tokenData);
    int myInt = tokenData[1] << 8 + tokenData[0];
    double myDouble = ((double)myInt) / 65536f;
    double dir = myDouble * 360 * d2r;
    return new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(dir) * scaleFactor, (float)Math.Sin(dir) * scaleFactor);
}
```

This results in even more haphazard coverage of particles.
[image]

Thinking that maybe two bytes worth of data is insufficient, I up it to 4:

```
        byte[] tokenData = new byte[4];
        rng.GetBytes(tokenData);
        int myInt = tokenData[3]<<24 + tokenData[2]<<16 + tokenData[1]<<8 + tokenData[0];
        double myDouble = ((double)myInt) / 4294967296;
```

This doesn't make it any better.
[image]

OK.  So maybe it has something to do with the way I'm using the sin/cos.  I rework the fn to be more like this:

```
public static Vector2 rndV2gtHalf(float scaleFactor)
{
    return scaleFactor * 
           new Vector2((float)(random.NextDouble() - 0.5f), (float)(random.NextDouble() - 0.5f));
}
```

Besides this generating a square-edged field of streams that grows to the edge of the screen, it is less random looking than the sin/cos attempts.
[image]

Nothing I've attempted seems to work.  So, repeating my question, how can I get more randomness from a random number generator?

Comment: Maybe it helped if you expressed your concerns in numerical form and not with images.

Comment: You are casting about essentially at random (ha ha) without actually thinking the problem through logically. Consider for example the idea that adding three random numbers together and taking their average is "more random" -- that is **less** uniformly random. When you roll one die over and over again you get one through six uniformly distributed. When you roll two dice and take the average, you'll get 3.5 17% of the time but 1 only 3% of the time. The more sums you make the *less* uniform the distribution gets; this is the Central Limit Theorem.

Comment: Given that the shape displayed barely changes when you change the randomness algorithm, the problem likely isn't in the randomness algorithm in the first place. You likely have a bug somewhere else in code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: Eric:  I agree, both with the bit about me flailing, and about the effect of averaging.  Still, it was adding then removing a dbl (again changing the range) that gave me more random results.  The strangest part tho was that it was on the scaleFactor, not the angle.  So, regarding your comment, what's the practical application -- what's the logical thinking to apply to make the RNG more random?  Regarding a bug elsewhere, besides the setting of the initial velocity, at each update, velocity is added to location.  that's it.

Comment: but in case you don't believe me, here's the code i use (sorry, but unformatted due to being in comments):
    public override void move(ImageObj obj, GameTime gameTime)
        {
            obj.Location += obj.velocity;
            if (
                    (obj.RectScaled.Right  < 0             ) |
                    (obj.RectScaled.Left   > G.screenSize.X) |
                    (obj.RectScaled.Bottom < 0             ) |
                    (obj.RectScaled.Top    > G.screenSize.Y)
                )
            {
                obj.alive = false;
            }
        }

Comment: My advice is to post a small, simple program that we can actually run and see the unusual output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To everyone who said the problem was someplace else, not in my random number routine, that there must have been a bug in some of my other code,,, you were right.

I discovered that by storing/retrieving my location in/from the Location of a rectangle, I had been truncating its components down to ints.

In retrospect, it should have been a clue that by playing with the scaleFactor, by adding then removing  a same-range random number, already realized to have been increasing the range of the number, I got my so-close-to-working solution to have numbers that actually were different enough when truncated to cover more of the range.

Not exactly sure who to credit with the answer for this.

My final routine code turned out to be:

```
public static double TwoPi = Math.PI * 2f;
public static Vector2 rndV2gtHalf(float scaleFactor)
{
    double dir = random.NextDouble() * TwoPi;
    return new Vector2(
                            (float)Math.Cos(dir) * scaleFactor,
                            (float)Math.Sin(dir) * scaleFactor
                        );
}
```

and here is the visual result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

On a whim, I decided to play with the scaleFactor, both adding and removing a rndm double.  The scaleFactor that was passed in has always been 2.5.

```
public static double TwoPi = Math.PI * 2f;
public static Vector2 rndV2gtHalf(float scaleFactor)
{
    scaleFactor = (float)(scaleFactor + random.NextDouble() - random.NextDouble());
    double dir = random.NextDouble() * TwoPi;
    return new Vector2  (
                            (float)Math.Cos(dir) * scaleFactor,
                            (float)Math.Sin(dir) * scaleFactor
                        );
}
```

Much to my surpise, this generated this far "fuller" displersion of particles:
[image]

Thinking that if some was good, more was better, I repeated the process 4 more times, but was unable to discern any difference.

[image]

There is still more emptiness near 0 and 180 degrees than I'd like, but this is a big improvement over what I had before.

I have no good understanding of why, but this effectively solves the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

here is an adapted class based on the RNGCryptoServiceProvider that I use regularly. The original author is Jim Mischel, who wrote a great [article](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=775) and the class.

My stochastics course lies a way back but isn't this "star" pattern typical when using a uniformly distributed random generator? As far as I remember a truly uniform random generator should not have any preferences and so the likelihood of any number to be drawn is equal. This means that the direction of your particle is also uniformly distributed around a circle without any preference, which ends up being a star, right?

```
/*
 * Adapted from Jim Mischel 
 * http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=775
*/
public class RandomEx
{
  private const int BufferSize = 1024;  // must be a multiple of 4
  private byte[] RandomBuffer;
  private int BufferOffset;
  private RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng;

  public RandomEx()
  {
    RandomBuffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    BufferOffset = RandomBuffer.Length;
  }

  private void FillBuffer()
  {
    rng.GetBytes(RandomBuffer);
    BufferOffset = 0;
  }

  public int Next()
  {
    if (BufferOffset >= RandomBuffer.Length)
    {
      FillBuffer();
    }
    int val = BitConverter.ToInt32(RandomBuffer, BufferOffset) & 0x7fffffff;
    BufferOffset += sizeof(int);
    return val;
  }

  public double NextDouble()
  {
    int val = Next();
    return (double)val / int.MaxValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: I implemented your solution and the result was almost identical to my very first picture: 28 radial wiggly streams with lots of empty space between them.  On the plus side, I did learn how to use BitConverter. But I'm still looking for more randomness.

Answer (score 0):

There's something called a [Von Neumann extractor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_extractor#Von_Neumann_extractor): if you have a weakly biased source of bits, take successive (non-overlapping) pairs; if they're identical, go to the next pair; if they're different, return the first one. This improves the randomness of the input stream at the expense of "wasting" a lot of bits.

However, as has been mentioned before, your problem seems to be located somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I've put your code to the test, and it works perfectly well for me. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to post images yet.

That said, there's probably a bug somewhere else that causes unwanted behavior.
To verify that, you can take a different approach to picking a random direction and check if it fixes the problem:

```
    public Vector2 getRandomVelocity(float scaleFactor, Random random)
    {
        float angle = MathHelper.ToRadians(random.Next(361));

        return new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(angle) * scaleFactor, (float)Math.Sin(angle) * scaleFactor);
    }
```